# Find all the cosets of $H$ in $G$ , where $G = \{ z\in \mathbb C \mid z \neq 0 \}$ , $H = \{ z \in\mathbb C \mid z^n = 1 , n\in\mathbb N \}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let, $G = \{z\in\mathbb C \mid z \neq 0\}$, $H = \{z\in\mathbb C \mid z^n = 1 , n\in\mathbb N\}$. Find the cosets of $H$ in $G$.

I have got the pictorial idea that how the cosets will look like concentric circle in complex plane, but I could not understant how to express those cosets and how to solve this problem in a rigorous way.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that. All roots of unity are dense in the unit circle, but they don't comprise all of the unit circle.

Comment: Yes, I have thought exactly in that way , but I am not getting why they don't comprise all of the unit circles.

Comment: For each $n\in \mathbb{N} $ the set $ \{z\in \mathbb{C} :z^n =1\} $ is finite and so the set $H$ is the countable union over all natural $n$ which results in a countable set. The unit circle is uncountable.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot , I just forgot that countable and uncountable things . Thank you.

Comment: I’m sorry, but your definition is ambiguous. Do you mean $H$ to be dependent on $n$, so that $H=\{z\in\Bbb C\mid z^n=1\}$, or did you mean $H=\{z\in\Bbb C\mid\exists n\in\Bbb Z, z^n=1\}$. Remember, it’s always dangerous to put quantification at the end. I recognize that by reading your text, one could decide that you almost surely meant the former, but the definition should stand on its own, without the necessity of interpretation.

Comment: Do I understand correctly you're just looking for:

$\{gH:g\in\Bbb R^\times, H= e^{2i\pi\cdot \Bbb Q/\Bbb Z}\}$

?

Comment: Thank you so much to all of you, I got the idea. And the definition was really ambiguous but I also feel the former is true, so I have just edited the question a little, since I wasn't sure about the fact so I couldn't understand those definition , I am sorry , now I have edited it.

Comment: Sir, I got the idea from your sketch , still I am facing problem to write it rigorously in mathematical language, can you please express it in language, actually what I can write in exam, I want to know how can I show that these are the forms of cosets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch of an idea:

$(1).\ $ Consider $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ and note that for each equivalence class, there is exactly one representative $0\le q< 1.$

$(2).\ $ the map $[q]\to 1^q$ is an isomorphism: $: \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow H.$

$(3).\ $ If $[z] \in \mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ then $z\sim w\Leftrightarrow zw^{-1}\in \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}.$ Now $z=re^{it}$ and $w=r'e^{is}$ then using  $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have that $z\sim w$ if and only if $zw^{-1}$ is a $p^{th}$ root of unity for some fixed rational $q=r/p.$ This means that $z$ and $w$ lie on the same circle and are such that $-s$ is the angle through which $z$ must be rotated to bring it to one of the $p$ roots of unity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution I got it .

Comment: @Shankhadeep You are welcome. Glad to help.

Comment: Sir, I got the idea from your sketch , still I am facing problem to write it rigorously in mathematical language, can you please express it in language, actually what I can write in exam.